# CSS Relative-Absolute position

Tags: html, css

I am new to web designing and trying to understand the concept of positioning in CSS. I have some understanding of element being positioned relative and absolute. In the fiddle below I have a `<div>` as parent to `<p>`. When I make `p` `position:absolute`, the border crashes unlike when I make my `<span>` `position:absolute`, it behaves as expected *(I am able to move the word in  element with  the border)*. Please point me what I am seeing wrong? Why is the border crashing only in case of `<p>` being positioned absolute

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
}

span {
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>possessions</span>
  <p>
    Five suspected gang members attacked two agents who were escorting them in a lift, the Investigative Committee said. The group was handcuffed and it was not immediately clear how they managed to free themselves to attack the guards. The two other suspects
    and three security officers were wounded. The suspects were accused of being part of a group known as GTA Gang, named after the violent game series Grand Theft Auto. The group of Central Asian nationals was suspected of killing 17 motorists in the
    Moscow area between 2012 and 2014. Cars were forced to stop on a main road and their drivers were killed for reasons as yet unknown; none of their were stolen.
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Making an element absolute means that it will go out of flow of the document, and since `<p>` is relative to `<div>`, `<p>` will position itself within `<div>` but will not respect the boundaries of `<div>`, just like what you are seeing.

Comment: Try making `<span>` the same length as `<p>`, you should see the same result

Comment: @Swellar  Thanks for info. Please explain why making  P absolute makes it not respect Div border?? I was in an idea that P would stay inside div border and move within the border(when I specify top-left-right-bottom). I see it happening for span. The only dfference with p and span is amount of text.

Comment: @Swellar I am in an understanding that div is an element with a specific border and P is child of div and is relative to div. So I am expecting it to stay within the border of div and move when I specify attributes like top-left-bottom-right. Please correct me if my understanding with absolute is wrong?

Comment: It would stay inside div,but since the length is long,it will go out of boundaries depending on where you put it. Just imagine that `<p>` is a flying block element. As I said, make the span the same length, it will also go out of boundaries or make p shorter.

Comment: @swellar One last thing- Do only elements in normal document flow get border?

Comment: @Swellar I see it happening when I make span as same length as P.  But I am confused at the point  Why doesn't border  remain same when text comes outside it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150842/discussion-between-sreemanth-jasti-and-swellar).

Answer (score 1):

> When set to absolute or fixed, the element is removed completely from the normal flow of the document.

so when you define for `p` element `position:absolute`,it removed from normal flow of the document and border get crashed. but when you don't define position for  `p` ,it get default position (static position) and stay in flow of the document and border have not crash.

You can use `relative` instead of `absolute` in p.

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  border:2px solid black;
  padding:10px;
  
  }
  
  p {
   position:relative;
   top:10px;
  }
  
  span{
   position:absolute;
   top:10px;
  }
```

```html
<div >
<span>possessions</span>
<p>
Five suspected gang members attacked two agents who were escorting them in a lift, the Investigative Committee said.
The group was handcuffed and it was not immediately clear how they managed to free themselves to attack the guards.
The two other suspects and three security officers were wounded.
The suspects were accused of being part of a group known as GTA Gang, named after the violent game series Grand Theft Auto.
The group of Central Asian nationals was suspected of killing 17 motorists in the Moscow area between 2012 and 2014. Cars were forced to stop on a main road and their drivers were killed for reasons as yet unknown; none of their  were stolen.
</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to avoid `position: absolute` unless you want

- element overlapping other elements or overlapped by other elements
- element removed from normal flow of document

I would recommend you to avoid `position: relative` unless you want

- element with descendant of `position: absolute` and you want current element to specify coordinate system for absolutely positioned descendant. Demo:

  ```css
  .relative {
    position: relative;

    /* optional styles for demo */
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .absolute {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    top: 50px;
    right: 15px;
    
    /* optional styles for demo */
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: tomato;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    text-align: center;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="relative">
    Position: relative;
    <div class="some-intermediate-container">
      <div class="absolute">
        Absolutely positioned descendant
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="absolute">
    Absolutely positioned relatively<br /> to document
  </div>
  ```
- element take original space before applying `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom`. Demo:

  ```css
  span {
    background-color: yellow;
  }

  .relative {
    position: relative;
    /* move to 10px bottom but preseve original occupied space */
    top: 15px;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <p><span>One</span> <span>Two</span> <span class="relative">Three</span> <span>Four</span></p>
  ```

---

If you just want move you `span` and `p` to `10px` below just use `margin-top` here. Demo:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
}

p {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

span {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>possessions</span>
  <p>
    Five suspected gang members attacked two agents who were escorting them in a lift, the Investigative Committee said. The group was handcuffed and it was not immediately clear how they managed to free themselves to attack the guards. The two other suspects
    and three security officers were wounded. The suspects were accused of being part of a group known as GTA Gang, named after the violent game series Grand Theft Auto. The group of Central Asian nationals was suspected of killing 17 motorists in the
    Moscow area between 2012 and 2014. Cars were forced to stop on a main road and their drivers were killed for reasons as yet unknown; none of their were stolen.
  </p>
</div>
```